# XML::LibXML Line Ending (whitespace) Problem

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2, xml-libxml

HI,
I am parsing an XML file using LibXML in Perl.
The problem that I have is the ending characters (whitespace) is treated as a text node. For instance, given an input like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE books [
    <!ELEMENT title  (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT year   (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT price  (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT book   (title, author, year, price)>
    <!ELEMENT books  (book*)>
]>
<books>
<book>
<title>Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
</books>
```

The parser thinks that the number of child of node "books" is 3, they are:

- text node (containing the char between `<books>` and `<book>`)
- element node of `<book>`
- text node (containing the char between `</book>` and `</books>`)

Question is how do I tell LibXML to ignore whitespaces? 
I tried with no_blanks (that is $parser = XML::LibXML->new(no_blanks => 1) when construction the parser) but it seems that it has no effect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use "s/\s+$//;" to remove all white space at the end of line.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot just blindly remove those whitespaces from each line because the results might not valid according to the DTD I use.

Comment: +1 for Giada De Laurentiis (well, and I like the question :)

Answer (score 2):

XML::LibXML::Parser has `$parser->keep_blanks(0);` . It's supposed to do the opposite of no_blanks - see if that works

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it does not help. I tried it on Linux and Cygwin.

Comment: worked for me. if I toggle this the text nodes containing the CRs go away.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly-speaking, `XML::LibXML` is doing the correct thing... there *are* three child-nodes of the `<books>` element. The question is, how are you parsing the content, and why is this a problem?

Assuming you've parsed your content and assigned the result to `$document`, you now have an instance of the `XML::LibXML::Document` class. Using this, you can get the `<books>` element by using `documentElement()`:

```
$books = $document->documentElement();
```

This returns an instance of `XML::LibXML::Element`. From this, you can get just the `<book>` child-elements using `getChildrenByTagName()`:

```
@book_elements = $books->getChildrenByTagName('book');
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hi,
I pretty much did as what you mentioned. In the snippet version it is

$dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => "books.xml");
$dom->validate();
$root = $dom->documentElement();
@x = $root->childNodes;

The size of @X is 3. It seems that LibXML is broken. The call validate() Does validates the dom against the DTD. I know this because if I swap the oder of title and auther the parser complains. However, the parser failed to understand from the DTD that the child of books can only be title, author, year and price, no PCDATA at all. So where does this textnode come from ?